# Where could I possibly be messing up in a for loop?

Tags: php

Here is what I am doing (php)

```
<?php

for($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i+2)
{
  echo $i;
}
?>
```

It drives me nuts,coz it does not work  [prints nothing, browser keeps trying to load]. But if I change `$i+2` to `$i++`, it works, and if I change it to `$i+1`, that does not work either.

I am out of my wits. What is going wrong?

Comment: `$i + 2` does not *change* the value of `$i`, it just computes the value of that expression.

Comment: you need to to update `$i = $i+2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It drives me nuts,coz it does not work [prints nothing, browser keeps trying to load]. But if I change `$i+2` to `$i++`, it works, and if I change it to `$i+1`, that does not work either.

`$i++` is equivalent to `$i = $i + 1`, note the assignment operator `=`,  it isn't present here `$i + 2` adds but doesn't update  ...

since `$i` is never updated, you have an infinite loop, where the script will probably reach the allowable time for processing and terminate.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `$i+2` to `$i = $i + 2` or `$i += 2`.
`$i++` means `$i += 1`.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 30; $i += 2)
{
  echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide some increment /decrement value to the for loop after each iteration.
$i+2 does not change the value of i. So what is happening in your case is the for loop finds the same value of i for each successive iteration.Consequently the termination condition is never met.**The for loop is hence stuck in an infinite loop.**

Change: `$i+1` to `$i=$i+1` or `$i+=1`.

`$i++` actually means `$i=$i+1`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change to `$i=$i+2`, because `$i++` is equal to `$i=$i+1`.